# How use SharedPreferences to change the font

Tags: android

By using this code I want to change font of a textview, but the program doesn't work.
What I should do?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("Prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
public String fonts = shared.getString("fonts", "BHOMA.ttf");
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    setFace();
}
protected void setFace()
{
    TextView txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/"+fonts+"");
     txt1.setTypeface(face);
}
```

}

and in prefs.class

public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        String fonts = prefs.getString("fonts", "Tahoma.ttf");
        Boolean b = prefs.getBoolean("FIRSTRUN", true);      
}
```

}

Comment: where you are saving value in SharedPreferences ?

Comment: and when you are saving value in SharedPreferences

Comment: I add codes to prefs.class..this codes:String fonts = prefs.getString("fonts", "Tahoma.ttf");----